# Python list how to identify the given number is in the range Challenge Question

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, list

In python am having the list like

```
mylist  = [100  30  400 340, 230, 160,  25]

Given number is : 239
```

My aim is i have to identify this 239(given number) is in the range of or inbetween of  the list each lement with +10 and - 10

Example i have to take the first value from list to verify that 243 is in between 100+10 and 100-10 Not that result false

same way have to compare to 30+10 , 30-10  then again 400+10 and 400-10 same like all

if any one of that inbetween the range i have to return as true if not match with any one then return false

How to do that

Here 239 in between 230+10 and 230-10 so no the result i will get as true

How to do this ??

Thank you in avance

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do your homework for you.  What have you tried?

Comment: Why is there a JavaScript tag if you're using Python

Comment: You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and a lambda function.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You may iterate on the element of your list, and for each test the expression `value-10 < x and x < value+10` that can be written in once in python  `value-10 < x < value+10`

```
def search_numbers(values, x):
    for value in values:
        if value - 10 < x < value + 10:
            print(f"Ok: {value}-10 < {x} < {value}+10")
            return True
    return False

mylist = [100, 30, 400, 340, 230, 160, 25]
print(search_numbers(mylist, 239))  # True
print(search_numbers(mylist, 243))  # False
```